# Creating a new table with the total count from 3 or more tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

So what I am trying to do is add the counts from 3 or more identical tables into one new table. Is this even something possible in SQL?

This is the working query I have:

```
select FirstID,
    sum(case when Color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) 'RED',
    sum(case when Color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) 'BLUE',
    sum(case when Color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) 'GREEN',
    sum(case when Color = 'Yellow' then 1 else 0 end) 'YELLOW'
from Table
group by FirstID
order by PrimaryDiagnosisCode

select SecondID,
    sum(case when Color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) 'RED',
    sum(case when Color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) 'BLUE',
    sum(case when Color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) 'GREEN',
    sum(case when Color = 'Yellow' then 1 else 0 end) 'YELLOW'
from Table
group by SecondID
order by SecondID

select ThirdID,
    sum(case when Color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) 'RED',
    sum(case when Color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) 'BLUE',
    sum(case when Color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) 'GREEN',
    sum(case when Color = 'Yellow' then 1 else 0 end) 'YELLOW'
from Table
group by ThirdID
order by ThirdID
```

So after I run the query I have 3 tables that look like this:

```
Name        RED     BLUE    GREEN     YELLOW
-----      -----   ------  -------  ----------  
ColorID1    52       1      3           5
ColorID2     2      27      73          9
ColorID3     0       2      3          50
```

How would I write a query to add a table with a new sum of all of the ID's of the 3 tables? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Union ALL' was hitting my table to many times because I have up to 50 some ID's so I used a unpivot instead and just grabed it in one go.

This is just a bit cleaner for my needs.

```
select *
into #Init1
from Table
where Color in ('Red','Blue','Green','Yellow')
       and ServiceDate >= '2016-01-01'
       and ServiceDate <= '2016-12-13'

select distinct Color, AccountID, TransactionID
,Diag
into #Diags
from #Init1
unpivot
(
       Diag
       for Problem in (FirstID,SecondID,ThirdID)
) as unpvt
order by Color, AccountID,TransactionID



select Diag,
    sum(case when Color = 'Red' then 1 else 0 end) 'RED',
    sum(case when Color = 'Blue' then 1 else 0 end) 'BLUE',
    sum(case when Color = 'Green' then 1 else 0 end) 'GREEN',
    sum(case when Color = 'Yellow' then 1 else 0 end) 'YELLOW'
from #Diags
group by Diag
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I correctly interpreted what you expect: If you want a total across 3 (or n) tables still grouped by Name you can create a global dataset of results using `UNION ALL` and then `GROUP BY` Name and sum each color:

```
declare @table_1 table([Name] nvarchar(50), RED  int, BLUE int, GREEN int, YELLOW int)
declare @table_2 table([Name] nvarchar(50), RED  int, BLUE int, GREEN int, YELLOW int)
declare @table_3 table([Name] nvarchar(50), RED  int, BLUE int, GREEN int, YELLOW int)

insert into @table_1 values
('ColorID1',52,1,3,5),('ColorID2',2,27,73,9),('ColorID3',0,2,3,50)

insert into @table_2 values
('ColorID1',1,2,3,4),('ColorID2',5,6,7,8),('ColorID3',9,10,11,12)

insert into @table_3 values
('ColorID1',10,20,30,40),('ColorID2',50,60,70,80),('ColorID3',90,100,110,120)

select * from @table_1
select * from @table_2
select * from @table_3

select tmp.[Name], SUM(tmp.RED) as RED, SUM(tmp.BLUE) as BLUE, SUM(tmp.GREEN) as GREEN, 
    SUM(tmp.YELLOW) as YELLOW 
from (
    select [Name],RED,BLUE,GREEN,YELLOW from @table_1 union all
    select [Name],RED,BLUE,GREEN,YELLOW from @table_2 union all
    select [Name],RED,BLUE,GREEN,YELLOW from @table_3
    --you can add more tables here
) tmp
group by tmp.[Name]
```

Here are the results:

[image]

The first three tables are your input tables, the last table (highlighted in red) is the overall result that sums values across input tables.

If you need to insert more tables you just have to add them to the `UNION ALL` section.

Comment: Thank you for your help. :)